MySQL 8 window functions optimization with multiple greatest-n-per-group
I'm struggling to make efficient this sort of query:
with a as (
    select
        -- the battery cycle
        cycles_bat_1,
        
        -- interested on a single result row per cycle, so using 'where rn = 1'
        row_number()                    over(partition by cycles_bat_1 order by timestamp) as rn,
        
        
        -- window for timestamp and energy
        
        -- the timestamp when we met this cycle for the first time
        first_value(timestamp)          over(partition by cycles_bat_1 order by timestamp) as timestamp,
        
        -- the battery total charged energy when we met this cycle for the first time
        first_value(e_charge_total)     over(partition by cycles_bat_1 order by timestamp) as charge,
        
        -- the battery total discharged energy when we met this cycle for the first time
        first_value(e_discharge_total)  over(partition by cycles_bat_1 order by timestamp) as discharge,
        
        
        -- window for min SoC
        
        -- the min SoC the battery had in this cycle
        first_value(soc_bat_1)          over(partition by cycles_bat_1 order by soc_bat_1 asc, timestamp) as soc_min,
        
        -- the timestamp when battery had the min SoC in this cycle for the first time (min timestamp for min SoC)
        first_value(timestamp)          over(partition by cycles_bat_1 order by soc_bat_1 asc, timestamp) as soc_min_time,
        
        -- window for max SoC
        
        -- the max SoC the battery had in this cycle
        first_value(soc_bat_1)          over(partition by cycles_bat_1 order by soc_bat_1 desc, timestamp) as soc_max,
        
        -- the timestamp when battery had the max SoC in this cycle for the first time (min timestamp for max SoC)
        first_value(timestamp)          over(partition by cycles_bat_1 order by soc_bat_1 desc, timestamp) as soc_max_time,


        -- etc windows
        
        first_value(t_bat_1)            over(partition by cycles_bat_1 order by t_bat_1 asc, timestamp) as temperature_min,
        first_value(timestamp)          over(partition by cycles_bat_1 order by t_bat_1 asc, timestamp) as temperature_min_time,
        first_value(t_bat_1)            over(partition by cycles_bat_1 order by t_bat_1 desc, timestamp) as temperature_max,
        first_value(timestamp)          over(partition by cycles_bat_1 order by t_bat_1 desc, timestamp) as temperature_max_time,

        first_value(p_bat_1)            over(partition by cycles_bat_1 order by p_bat_1 asc, timestamp) as power_min,
        first_value(timestamp)          over(partition by cycles_bat_1 order by p_bat_1 asc, timestamp) as power_min_time,
        first_value(p_bat_1)            over(partition by cycles_bat_1 order by p_bat_1 desc, timestamp) as power_max,
        first_value(timestamp)          over(partition by cycles_bat_1 order by p_bat_1 desc, timestamp) as power_max_time,
        
        first_value(v_bat_1)            over(partition by cycles_bat_1 order by v_bat_1 asc, timestamp) as voltage_min,
        first_value(timestamp)          over(partition by cycles_bat_1 order by v_bat_1 asc, timestamp) as voltage_min_time,
        first_value(v_bat_1)            over(partition by cycles_bat_1 order by v_bat_1 desc, timestamp) as voltage_max,
        first_value(timestamp)          over(partition by cycles_bat_1 order by v_bat_1 desc, timestamp) as voltage_max_time,
        
        first_value(c_bat_1)            over(partition by cycles_bat_1 order by c_bat_1 asc, timestamp) as current_min,
        first_value(timestamp)          over(partition by cycles_bat_1 order by c_bat_1 asc, timestamp) as current_min_time,
        first_value(c_bat_1)            over(partition by cycles_bat_1 order by c_bat_1 desc, timestamp) as current_max,
        first_value(timestamp)          over(partition by cycles_bat_1 order by c_bat_1 desc, timestamp) as current_max_time
        
    from solarman_record
    where soc_bat_1 > 0
)
select 
    *
from a
where rn=1;

The query took:
# Query_time: 1145.771265  Lock_time: 0.000003 Rows_sent: 155  Rows_examined: 155

in this context:
mysql> select count(*) from solarman_record;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   834898 |
+----------+

mysql> show create table solarman_record;
| solarman_record | CREATE TABLE `solarman_record` (
  `timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date` date GENERATED ALWAYS AS (cast(`timestamp` as date)) STORED NOT NULL,
  `year` year GENERATED ALWAYS AS (year(`timestamp`)) STORED NOT NULL,
  `month` tinyint GENERATED ALWAYS AS (month(`timestamp`)) STORED NOT NULL,
  `day` tinyint GENERATED ALWAYS AS (dayofmonth(`timestamp`)) STORED NOT NULL,
  `hour` tinyint GENERATED ALWAYS AS (hour(`timestamp`)) STORED NOT NULL,
  `minute` tinyint GENERATED ALWAYS AS (minute(`timestamp`)) STORED NOT NULL,
  `second` tinyint GENERATED ALWAYS AS (second(`timestamp`)) STORED NOT NULL,
  `P_LOAD_SYS` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `P_OUTPUT_R` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `P_OUTPUT_S` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `P_OUTPUT_T` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `P_OUTPUT_TOTAL` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `P_PCC_R` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `P_PCC_S` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `P_PCC_T` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `P_PCC_TOTAL` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `P_PV_EXT` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `T_AMBIENT` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `E_CHARGE_TODAY` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `E_CHARGE_TOTAL` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `E_CONSUMPTION_TODAY` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `E_CONSUMPTION_TOTAL` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `C_BAT_1` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `C_OUTPUT_R` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `C_OUTPUT_S` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `C_OUTPUT_T` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `C_PCC_R` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `C_PCC_S` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `C_PCC_T` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `C_PV_1` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `C_PV_2` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `CYCLES_BAT_1` smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `E_DISCHARGE_TODAY` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `E_DISCHARGE_TOTAL` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `E_EXPORT_TODAY` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `E_EXPORT_TOTAL` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `FAULT` binary(36) NOT NULL DEFAULT '\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0',
  `E_GENERATION_TODAY` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `E_GENERATION_TOTAL` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `E_IMPORT_TODAY` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `E_IMPORT_TOTAL` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `T_MODULE` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `P_BAT_1` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `P_PV_1` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `P_PV_2` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `T_RADIATOR` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `SOC_BAT_1` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `SOH_BAT_1` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `STATUS` tinyint NOT NULL,
  `T_BAT_1` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `V_BAT_1` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `V_PV_1` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `V_PV_2` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `V_R` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `V_S` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `V_T` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `P_PV_TOTAL` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `COUNTDOWN` smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`timestamp`),
  KEY `IX_P_PV_TOTAL` (`P_PV_TOTAL`),
  KEY `IX_DATE` (`date`),
  KEY `IX_YEAR` (`year`),
  KEY `IX_MONTH` (`month`),
  KEY `IX_DAY` (`day`),
  KEY `IX_HOUR` (`hour`),
  KEY `IX_MINUTE` (`minute`),
  KEY `IX_SECOND` (`second`),
  KEY `IX_SOC_BAT_1` (`SOC_BAT_1`),
  KEY `IX_SOH_BAT_1` (`SOH_BAT_1`),
  KEY `IX_CYCLES_BAT_1` (`CYCLES_BAT_1`),
  KEY `IX_E_GENERATION_TODAY` (`E_GENERATION_TODAY`),
  KEY `IX_E_GENERATION_TOTAL` (`E_GENERATION_TOTAL`),
  KEY `IX_E_CONSUMPTION_TODAY` (`E_CONSUMPTION_TODAY`),
  KEY `IX_E_CONSUMPTION_TOTAL` (`E_CONSUMPTION_TOTAL`),
  KEY `IX_E_CHARGE_TODAY` (`E_CHARGE_TODAY`),
  KEY `IX_E_CHARGE_TOTAL` (`E_CHARGE_TOTAL`),
  KEY `IX_E_DISCHARGE_TODAY` (`E_DISCHARGE_TODAY`),
  KEY `IX_E_DISCHARGE_TOTAL` (`E_DISCHARGE_TOTAL`),
  KEY `IX_E_EXPORT_TODAY` (`E_EXPORT_TODAY`),
  KEY `IX_E_EXPORT_TOTAL` (`E_EXPORT_TOTAL`),
  KEY `IX_E_IMPORT_TODAY` (`E_IMPORT_TODAY`),
  KEY `IX_E_IMPORT_TOTAL` (`E_IMPORT_TOTAL`),
  CONSTRAINT `solarman_record_chk_1` CHECK ((`status` between 0 and 7))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

I tried to mix in a GROUP BY, but there is no first_value() aggregation function...
I'm not interested in speed. I want to understand if, how and why this query can be optimized so that I can reuse the knowledge in other contexts.
I'm using MySQL 8.0 (on windows), so I'm interested in both the general theory (all compliant DBA) and specific MySQL quirks.
Any suggestion is appreciated.

This is the next try:
with x as (
    select 
        cycles_bat_1,
        min(timestamp) timestamp,
        min(soc_bat_1) soc_min,
        max(soc_bat_1) soc_max,
        min(t_bat_1) t_min,
        max(t_bat_1) t_max,
        min(p_bat_1) p_min,
        max(p_bat_1) p_max,
        min(v_bat_1) v_min,
        max(v_bat_1) v_max,
        min(c_bat_1) c_min,
        max(c_bat_1) c_max
    FROM solarman_record 
    WHERE soc_bat_1 > 0
    GROUP BY cycles_bat_1
)
select 
    x.cycles_bat_1,
    x.timestamp,
    (select e_charge_total from solarman_record where timestamp=x.timestamp) charge,
    (select e_discharge_total from solarman_record where timestamp=x.timestamp) discharge,
    x.soc_min,
    (select min(timestamp) from solarman_record where cycles_bat_1=x.cycles_bat_1 and soc_bat_1=x.soc_min) soc_min_time,
    x.soc_max,
    (select min(timestamp) from solarman_record where cycles_bat_1=x.cycles_bat_1 and soc_bat_1=x.soc_max) soc_max_time,
    x.t_min,
    (select min(timestamp) from solarman_record where cycles_bat_1=x.cycles_bat_1 and t_bat_1=x.t_min) t_min_time,
    x.t_max,
    (select min(timestamp) from solarman_record where cycles_bat_1=x.cycles_bat_1 and t_bat_1=x.t_max) t_max_time,
    x.p_min,
    (select min(timestamp) from solarman_record where cycles_bat_1=x.cycles_bat_1 and p_bat_1=x.p_min) p_min_time,
    x.p_max,
    (select min(timestamp) from solarman_record where cycles_bat_1=x.cycles_bat_1 and p_bat_1=x.p_max) p_max_time,
    x.v_min,
    (select min(timestamp) from solarman_record where cycles_bat_1=x.cycles_bat_1 and v_bat_1=x.v_min) v_min_time,
    x.v_max,
    (select min(timestamp) from solarman_record where cycles_bat_1=x.cycles_bat_1 and v_bat_1=x.v_max) v_max_time,
    x.c_min,
    (select min(timestamp) from solarman_record where cycles_bat_1=x.cycles_bat_1 and c_bat_1=x.c_min) c_min_time,
    x.c_max,
    (select min(timestamp) from solarman_record where cycles_bat_1=x.cycles_bat_1 and c_bat_1=x.c_max) c_max_time
from x;

Results are exactly the same. Timings are not:
# Query_time: 14.007292  Lock_time: 0.000005 Rows_sent: 155  Rows_examined: 8349385

Nevertheless I'm not satisfied yet, I think there's room for further improvement (multiple subqueries on the same partial-filtered space is a smell).
If you have further suggestions I'll be glad to accept a better answer.
